# SAML 2.0 SSO for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, single-sign-on, saml

Where can I dig up a Ruby or Ruby on Rails library for SAML 2.0 SSO. I have a set of enterprise applications that are to be built but need to have federated login from a central authentication system. I have used SAML 1.1 and SAML 2.0 in a Microsoft .Net environment but have yet to see a library that handles both SAML Providers and Consumers for Ruby on Rails. Can someone point me in the right direction or tell me if I need to build the library myself?

Comment: I am looking for free libraries that implement both sides of the SAML spec, identity provider and requester. I am not looking for one sided client libraries which were implemented by a company as a way to pull in revenue. We must build a central Identity Provider for our internal systems as well as allow all of our applications to be the requesters. We are not interested in partnering with a Identity Provider.

Answer (score -17, accepted):

The best places to look are [Ruby Toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.com/) and [Rubygems.org](http://rubygems.org/) - if it's not there, you may try Github, but your chances are slim now.

My rule is: estimate how long it would take you to build it yourself. If you have spend a reasonable amount of time (say, 10%) on finding an existing solution, but none is out there (or working), then code it yourself.

Comment: This isn't really a useful answer.

Comment: Excellent pro life tip. What is your rule for building it yourself vs. buying it?

Comment: I'd argue that the Roll Your Own approach is less advisable when it comes to security: a naive implementation could easily introduce a security vulnerability.

Comment: Not a useful answer. I believe that you omit many important things. Estimating the cost to build something is not enough. There is a maintenance cost as well: how often will you need to update your solution to keep up to date with the changes of the standards/APIs involved? Do you have enough knowledge about this particular subject to roll out your own solution? Gems exist for a reason: you delegate these issues to the gem and put your trust in the maintainers with the belief that they are doing things in the most appropriate way possible.

Comment: uneven answer for this question

Answer (score 20):

I played with this one once: https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml
It might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Oddly enough, I just came across this today as well.  Seems like there are a few active forks and example application out there as well.  Although, I am not certain that it supports SAML 1.1...

Comment: it is not a full featured saml client yet, so it only supports some IdPs.

Comment: The official version of `ruby-saml` does not support encrypted responses as of yet. There are however a couple of forks and working branches that are trying to add it in. fyi, in case this is something you want right away.

Comment: Nowadays ruby-saml supports encrypted assertions

Answer (score -1):

AssureBridge SSOExchange is a service that supports SAML 1.1 and 2.0.  It is available with a simple Ruby connector that integrates simply into Ruby apps without the need for the developer to know any SAML.  It typically requires only a few lines of code in you r application.

Check it out at: http://www.assurebridge.com/integrations/

Comment: This feels like an ad for a commercial product, the OP was looking for FOSS solutions.