# SSO (Single sign-on) and ADFS (Active Directory Federation Services) with Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, adfs

I'm trying to understand how to integrate SSO (Single sign-on) and ADFS (Active Directory Federation Services) into an existing Ruby On Rails application hosted on a linux environment served by nginx.

Considering a **partner** (a company using Active record directory) and a **service provider** (the rails application).

It seems that the service provider web server must run an ADFS Web Agent that will handle the authentication process with the partner and ultimately redirect the user to the rails app with a token an a claim that would be used to identify the user in the app.

My main concern is about this ADFS Web Agent:

**Am I understanding correctly that it must be running on the service provider side ?** (I'm not interested on the partner side). If so, what would be the best way to integrate ADFS SSO with our app that is served by nginx on a linux OS? Do I need a windows server running a federation server ?

Thank you in advance for any help !

Comment: Are you using devise or omniauth? I had a similar situation configuring SSO for shibboleth/touchstone and found an omniauth strategy for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADFS handles two protocols - WS-Fed and SAML. ADFS 3.0 handles the Authorisation code grant in OAuth 2.0 (but not OpenID Connect),

So to get your Rails app. to talk to ADFS, it needs to support one of those protocols.

If it can do that, there is no need for any other server.

Perhaps something like [ruby-saml](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/ruby-saml).

Look here: [SAML 2.0 SSO for Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4232244/9922)

The other approach is to use OAuth / REST to get to some intermediate federation server and then SAML / WS-Fed out the other side.

Auth0 and Ping-Federate support this kind of approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using omniauth or if you are able to use it have a look at this: https://github.com/highgroove/omniauth-saml-rstr

Comment: Does that means that I don't need an AD FS web agent as stated in this document? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx

Comment: I still had to set up a shibboleth/SAML service provider to communicate with the campus network so I think you will probably have to do something similar.

Comment: NO - that's a very old reference to Server 2008 and refers to ADFS 1.1. In Server 2008 R2, ADFS 2.0 was a downloadable component and the agent concept was scrapped. The current level is ADFS 3.0 on Server 2012 R2.

Comment: @nzpcmad Thanks for the heads up. According to this doc for ADFS 2.0 https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd807050(v=ws.10).aspx it seems that I will still need to have a resource federation server running on my side that will handle the authentication process with the identity provider right ?